How to turn line-based pipe into continuous stream?
In my ongoing quest to get .po files sensibly under git version control, I have written this script for use in diff and filter-clean:
msgcat --no-location --no-wrap --sort-output - | msgattrib --no-obsolete - | grep -Ev '^"POT-Creation-Date|^"PO-Revision-Date|^"Last-Translator|^"X-Generator'
The .gitconfig entries to call this script look like this:
[diff "podiff"]
    textconv = cat "$1" | "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/podiff
    cachetextconv = true
[filter "pocomments"]
    clean = "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/podiff
    smudge = cat "$1" # NOP; enable the other one temporarily to affect files on checkout, restore, etc., but please do not commit it -Zsar 2024-06-10
#   smudge = "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/podiff
    required

Each of the steps accomplishes one crucial function:

Refactors and unrelated code changes make source location and entry order change incessantly. This msgcat invocation normalises those, so the commit-tet files do not have these changes.
Obsolete entries double the size of change sets whenever a msgid changes. We have version control -> this msgattrib invocation removes them.
These fields in the metadata entry of a .po file change every time someone edits it with a dedicated tool - we have version control -> this grep invocation removes them.

Now another hurdle came up. Notice that --no-wrap in the front? It does not work.
Furthermore, the wrapping is not stable: Every odd commit, someone gets a word flipped between lines without human changes.
Way furthermore, related tool Poedit also has a "Wrap at" setting, disabling which also does not work. (Because it delegates to the gettext tools, no surprise there. But it means there is no way for me to normalise the files 'just this once' and be done with it. - Hence I use a git filter in the first place.)
Very well, I figured, and tested this invocation to remove them: sed -z -e 's/\"\n\"//'.
It is to concatenate any wrapped lines in 'msgid' and 'msgstr', such that the tools may wrap them however they please, every day another way, for all I care.

It works stand-alone: sed -z -e 's/\"\n\"//' test.po prints the expected output.
It works when piped into from cat: cat test.po | sed -z -e 's/\"\n\"//' prints the expected output.
When added to the existing script, however, the sed step has no effect.

It would seem that it receives the input line-by-line. I tried putting it in front of grep for no improvement, and I cannot move it in front of the other two, as msgcat and msgattrib have their "I like my wrappings random" issue that sparked the whole ordeal to begin with.
Can I stream the output of grep, or more generally the output of a line-based pipe, so my stream editor can do its thing?
(Note: There are a lot of answers on this site that go "sed cannot do this" - but sed is specifically designed to not care about line breaks, so that sounds like misinformation. From the man page:

Sed  is  a  stream editor.  A stream editor is used to perform basic text transformations on an input stream (a file or input from a pipeline). [...] sed works by making only one pass over the input(s)[.]

emphasis mine
The problem is quite clearly, that there is more than one input, the very string I want to replace, split between them.)

Pipes are always continuous streams – the reader generally cannot distinguish write boundaries. (The source program may decide to buffer its output and flush it line-by-line or block-by-block, but that's rarely distinguishable.)
It seems that you have the opposite problem, i.e. the -z effectively tells 'sed' to treat its entire input as a single very long "line", and by default its s// operation replaces only the first match in that "line".
Add the /g option to change that:
msgattrib | grep | sed -z -e 's/\"\n\"//g'


If I execute this with a preceeding cat test.po | on the command line, it works perfectly, but the git filter suddenly does nothing, not even the preceeding stages: comments filtered by msgcat are still there, grep-ped lines are still there, sed has no effect at all. ... Any idea why? I'd have expected an error, but it just seems to suddenly ignore that the filter exists. - Meh, I'll update the question with my .gitconfig - did not expect a problem at this step.

With the basic cat | sed test I had been "too smart" - as you say, only the first occurence is replaced, it does not actually work. - Well, in my test file, I only had a single one. ~~ Lesson: Always use realistic test data.

Doh! "Too smart" indeed, quotation marks included. I was testing it in a submodule, not in a "real" repository - those do not have a local git config, so they do not execute the filter. Nvm. everything works, except in front of the screen. Checkmark + Upvote.
